# How to have a variable that could be a one of three predefined objects

Tags: c#, class, polymorphism

My code lets a user create a question and answer pair. There are three types the answer can be: either a NumericalAnswer, RangedAnswer or a ShortAnswer (a string).

I have the base Question Class:

```
class QuestionClass
{
    private string question;
    private AnswerClass answer;

    public string Question
    {
        get { return question; }
        set { question = value; }
    }

    public AnswerClass Answer
    {
        get { return answer; }
        set { answer = value; }
    }

    public QuestionClass(string question, AnswerClass answer)
    {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
}
```

All the answer types are inherited from an empty base class AnswerClass. The Answer classes are:

```
class NumericalAnswer : AnswerClass
{
    private float answer;

    public float Answer
    {
        get { return answer; }
        set { answer = value; }
    }
}

class RangedAnswer : AnswerClass
{
    private float lowerBound;
    private float upperBound;

    public float LowerBound
    {
        get { return lowerBound; }
        set { lowerBound = value; }
    }

    public float UpperBound
    {
        get { return upperBound; }
        set { upperBound = value; }
    }
}

class ShortAnswer : AnswerClass
{
    private string[] answer;

    public string[] Answer
    {
        get { return answer; }
        set { answer = value; }
    }
}
```

However, for example, if I create a question with a RangedAnswer and try to access the lowerBound variable I can't. If you know how I would be able to have multiple Answer classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use generics:

```
public class QuestionClass<T> where T : AnswerClass
{
    private string question;
    private T answer;

    public string Question
    {
        get { return question; }
        set { question = value; }
    }

    public T Answer
    {
        get { return answer; }
        set { answer = value; }
    }

    public QuestionClass(string question, T answer)
    {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
var ra = new RangedAnswer();
ra.LowerBound = 10;
ra.UpperBound = 20;
var q = new QuestionClass<RangedAnswer>("Test range?", ra);
q.Answer.LowerBound.Dump();
```

**EDIT** To support creating a list holding multiple question types..

Would something like this work?

```
    public abstract class QuestionClass { 

    }

    public class QuestionClass<T> : QuestionClass where T: AnswerClass
    {
        private string question;
        private T answer;

        public string Question
        {
            get { return question; }
            set { question = value; }
        }

        public T Answer
        {
            get { return answer; }
            set { answer = value; }
        }

        public QuestionClass(string question, T answer)
        {
            this.question = question;
            this.answer = answer;
        }
    }

And usage like this:

void Main()
{
    var ra = new RangedAnswer();
    ra.LowerBound = 10;
    ra.UpperBound = 20;

    var na = new NumericalAnswer();
    na.Answer = 25;

    var q1 = new QuestionClass<RangedAnswer>("Test range?", ra);
    var q2 = new QuestionClass<NumericalAnswer>("Numberic?", na);

    var list = new List<QuestionClass>();
    list.Add(q1);
    list.Add(q2);

    foreach (var q in list)
    {
        var rat = q as QuestionClass<RangedAnswer>;
        if (rat != null) {
            rat.Answer.LowerBound.Dump();
        }
        var nat = q as QuestionClass<NumericalAnswer>;
        if (nat != null) {
            nat.Answer.Answer.Dump();           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only issue with this is I now can't make a:

    List<QuestionClass>

of all three answer types can I?

Comment: @cookies Just edited my answer with some changes to support creating Lists of multiple question types

Comment: Yup that does exactly what I was trying to do - thank you :) I tried using an interface but still ended up with the same problems.

Comment: You can replace the abstract `QuestionClass` with an Interface and would still work. The key is make the List of a common non-generic base type